# Passing variable length array of c strings as function argument

Tags: c, exc-bad-access, c-strings

In my main function, I declare a variable length array of c strings and then pass it into a function called secondPass()

In secondPass(), I run a loop that determines the contents of a string called dec_instruction, then I try to add it to my array.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /* Logic to decide num_commands */

    char machine_instructions[num_commands][11];
    secondPass(machine_instructions, num_commands);
}


secondPass(char **machine_instructions, int num_commands){
    for(int i = 0; i < num_commands; ++i){
        char dec_instruction[11];

        /* Logic to decide contents of dec_instruction */

        strcat(machine_instructions[i], dec_instruction);
    }
}
```

Sorry I can't post the complete contents of my code.  This is for a class project and the rules on sharing code are pretty strict.

Anyway, the strcat() line near the end throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS when on the second iteration, when i = 1.  As far as I can tell, dec_instruction is a valid c string like any other.  What's causing my error?

Comment: `char **` cannot point to `char [][]`. `machine_instructions[1]` will be `sizeof(char*)` past `machine_instructions[0]`

Comment: You should have gotten a type error from your compiler for either the call or the function declaration.

Comment: `char dec_instruction[11]; ...
        strcat(machine_instructions[i], dec_instruction);` is a problem as code attempts to concatenate a string to an array that is not certainly a _string_.  Ask yourself, what are the contents of `dec_instruction[]` before the `strcat()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument `char **machine_instructions` does not denote a 2D-Array of type `char[][11]` but a pointer to a pointer to a char. This is often used as a pointer to an "array" of pointers, but it is never an array of arrays of chars.

So in your code, `machine_instructions[i]` will try to dereference a pointer to char, but the content you pass consists of plain characters and not of pointer values. Therefore the `BAD_EXCESS`.

Using `char machine_instructions[][11]` should solve the problem.